# Как найти в двумерном массиве размера N×N минимальный элемент главной диагонали квадратного массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, m;
  int a[500][500], min = a[0][0];
  cin >> n;

  //Ввод массива
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      cin >> a[i][j];
    }
  }
  min = a[0][0];
  //Поиск минимума
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[j][j] > min) {
             min = a[j][j];
        }
    }
  }

  cout << min;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте условие проверки на нахождение на главной диагонали и объявляйте минимальный элемент после ввода массива

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, m;
  int a[500][500], min = a[0][0];
  cin >> n;

  //Ввод массива
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      cin >> a[i][j];
    }
  }
  min = a[0][0];
  //Поиск минимума
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[j][j] < min && i == j) {
             min = a[j][j];
        }
    }
  }

  cout << min;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: @ДаниилШаронов пожалуйста. Потом для тренировки можете найти максимальный элемент на побочной диагонали.

Comment: Ну и зачем вы n раз выполняете одну и ту же проверку? Зачем сравнивать min  и a[0][0], если вы изначально присвоили min = a[0][0]?  С таким же успехом  можно каждую тривиальную операцию превратить в сложную и говорить, что главное она выдает правильный результат. Я этот ответ не считаю полезным

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну не считайте, Ваше дело:)
я всего лишь минимально оптимизировал код пользователя до рабочего состояния. Я не вижу смысла под корень переделывать программу, как любят многие пользователи этого ресурса.

Comment: Это не ответ, а издевательство. `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) if (a[j][j] < min) min = a[j][j];` вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы собираетесь ввести четверть миллиона чисел с клавиатуры? Или генерируйте эти числа, или берите поскромнее размер массива. Не нужно использовать лишние объекты и не нужен никакой вложенный цикл для проверки элементов только главной диагонали. Все очень просто:

```
const int n = 5;
int a[n][n];
//Ввод массива
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}    
//Поиск минимума
int min = a[0][0];

for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) 
    if (a[j][j] < min) 
            min = a[j][j];  

cout << min;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    constexpr size_t size = 4; // этапа компиляции
    int arr[size][size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    

    int min = numeric_limits<int>::max(); // макс. значение int'а
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    { 
        if (arr[i][j] <= min)
            min = arr[i][j];
        j++; // сдвиг по row
    }

    cout << min << endl;
}
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно - `int min = numeric_limits<int>::max();` - взять просто любой элемент. `[0][0]` точно имеется.